# Is the Lipschitz constant of $f$ equal to $\|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz and $[f] := \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb R^d; x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|}$ its Lipschitz constant. By Rademacher theorem, $f$ is differentiable a.e., so $\nabla f$ is defined a.e.

> Is it true that $\|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty} = [f]$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: @ThomasKojar From your link, I get that $\|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty} \le [f]$. For the reverse inequality, Julien's proof (in *Question 2.2*) requires that $f$ is differentiable *everywhere*.

Comment: You may want to check out the reference at wiki where it is stated that "any Lipschitz function on Ω is an element of the space W1,∞(Ω)".  The reference is to Evans and Gariepy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Theorem 1.41 of my book *Lipschitz Algebras* (second edition). But you must interpret ``$\|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty}$'' to mean $\|\,|\nabla f|\,\|_{L^\infty}$ (sup of the norm of the gradient taken in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: I should have specified "second edition". Edited.

Comment: Hi Nik!  Do you prove that via Sobolev spaces, or by a more elementary argument?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Oh, it's pretty elementary. The $\leq$ part is easy, in the opposite direction pick any two points, $p$ and $q$, draw a line joining them, and attempt to argue that $d(p,q) \leq$ the derivative of $f$ restricted to that line, in absolute value.

Comment: That doesn't quite work because the derivative might not exist a.e. on every line, but you can thicken that line and integrate over a ball lying in the hyperplane perpendicular to the line joining $p$ and $q$.

Comment: (I doubt this is my argument, but if not I don't remember where it's from.)

Comment: *argue that $|f(p)-f(q)| \leq$ the derivative of $f$ restricted to that line times $d(p,q)$